# What userAgent use in cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

```
debug($session->read());
Array
(
    [Config] => Array
        (
            [userAgent] => 85b3b055be0e89d07016e8c67e3e9d69
            [time] => 1292403988
            [timeout] => 10
        )

)
```

What userAgent in Session use for. I think it like this : `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.8) Gecko/20100202 Firefox/3.5.8 FirePHP/0.4`

Comment: couldn't understand what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with this setting in /app/config/core.php:

```
/**
 * When set to false, HTTP_USER_AGENT will not be checked
 * in the session. You might want to set the value to false, when dealing with
 * older versions of IE, Chrome Frame or certain web-browsing devices and AJAX
 */
    Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', true);
```

It's simply a [hash](http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/cake-session/#l-151) of the user agent used as extra security measure to ensure the session cookie is unique to one machine/browser.

Comment: uhm, thankyou. I thinked i can get browser's info from this .

Comment: @meo Just use `env('HTTP_USER_AGENT')`.